# How to print elements in list with double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

I have a for loop that prints out each line in the text as a element and appends it to the list. It is putting it with single quotes, however I would like it to placed in the element with a double quote. Not sure what to use and where to start.

My file contains

```
google.com 
yahoo.com
facebook.com
```

The script I have is

```
with open('file') as target:
    addresses=[]
    for i in target:
        addresses.append(i)
print(addresses)
```

The result I would like is

```
["google.com", "yahoo.com", "facebook.com"]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you need quotes, and double quotes specifically? Are you trying to generate a JSON array? That would just be `json.dumps([i.strip() for i in target])`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the *list* `['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'facebook.com']` (which is only *displayed* with quotes; it doesn't *contain* any) is different from the string `'["google.com", "yahoo.com", "facebook.com"]'`.

Comment: quote is not part of string - Python adds it only when you want to print list at once. If you want different quote then convert list to string manually and add quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) for this, and use [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) to remove trailing spaces and linebreaks.

```
import json

with open('test.txt') as target:
    addresses=[]
    for i in target:
        addresses.append(i.rstrip())

print(json.dumps(addresses))
```

Output:

```
["google.com", "yahoo.com", "facebook.com"]
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks for providing a solution. Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned before, Python only prints single quotes, if the type of given element is string, as in your case. If you need to have explicitly double quotes around your strings, then use f-strings:

```
with open('file') as target:
    addresses=[]
    for i in target:
        addresses.append(f"\"{i.rstrip()}\"")
print(addresses)
```

It will give you

```
['"google.com"', '"yahoo.com"', '"facebook.com"']
```

which is probably what you're looking for.